# R Plotly: add more legend to points from scatter plot

Tags: r, legend, plotly

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

`x y info1 info2 info3`

I am trying to plot the data with r plotly:

`plot_ly(data=df, x=x, y=y, mode="lines+markers", color = info1)`

Is there a way to display info2/info3 when passing the cursor on one point of the data?

**EDIT**: Example

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="
y   x   info1   info2
John    1   group1  18.32929
John    10  group1  29
John    100 group1  13
Emily   1   group2  4
Emily   10  group2  10
Emily   100 group2  20")
```

`plot_ly(data=df, x=x, y=y, mode="lines+markers", color = info1)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3RRQ.png)

I would like when I pass on a point to also display the info2 such as John
group1
18.32929

Answer (score 1):

As per mentionned in the [documentation](https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#custom-hover-text), you can pass custom hover info by specifying the `hoverinfo` parameter:

```
df %>%
  plot_ly(x = x, y = y, mode = "lines+markers", color = info1,
          hoverinfo = "text",
          text = paste(info1, info2))
```

Which gives:

[image]